# postgresql where clause for ordered strings not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am currently working on a query where i have ordered by name as per example,
select * from users order by name

```
andrew
bolahan
charles
dan
...
```

I wish to add a where clause where by i can retrieve all rows after a selected name, consider the following example:

```
select * from users where name > 'bolahan' ORDER BY 'bolahan'
```

should retrieve

```
charles
dan
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can do like that: `WHERE name > 'Bolahan'`, what is your problem ?

Comment: The query works as you have shown: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/88664/1 I guess there is something you are not telling us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by name:

```
select * from users where name > 'bolahan' ORDER BY name ASC;
```